# Create new feature class from tuple by changing Object Id

Tags: select, feature-class, list

I have feature class with 49 records. `OID = [0,...,48]`. I created 2 random non-repetitive feature classes containing 9 `OIDs`.

```
in_FC = "E:/gis payannameh/TABU search/data/90spring_new.shp"
out_FC = r"E:\gis payannameh\Pychram_tabu\random wells"
numSets = 2
setSize = 9
rawIDs = sorted([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_FC,'OID@')])
Network_well = []
while (len(Network_well) < numSets):
    candidate = list(rawIDs)
    random.shuffle(candidate)
    subset = ','.join([str(id) for id in sorted(candidate[:setSize])])
    if (subset not in Network_well):
        Network_well.append(subset)
nwell = tuple(Network_well)
for i in range(len(nwell)):

    templayer = "templayer_{}".format(i)
    sql = "{} IN ({})".format("FID", nwell[i])
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_FC,"templayer_{}".format(i),sql)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(templayer,out_FC,"net{}".format(i))
```

the output of `nwell=('1,3,10,12,18,32,35,42,47', '0,8,23,29,31,32,37,39,44')`.

How can I write code that, for example, removes 5 first item from each `nwell` membership and replace with 5 random other `OIDs`.
for example new `nwell = ('**2,4,6,23,26**,32,35,42,47','**1,7,13,15,24**,32,37,39,44')`

Comment: Please don't delete closed questions then repost under a different account.  How to manage a list of lists is more of a pure Python task.  Formatting the lists as strings is most of your issue here. As a rule, maintain the list as a list as long as possible, then convert to a string with `str.join()` at the last moment.

Comment: @Vince. thank for your advise. I only wanted to ask understandable question.